# Working with embedded resources

Tags: c#, resources, drawing, visio

I have an application that works with Visio drawing control and it needs to use a file with shapes for Visio drawing. I want to embed that file (stencil.vss) into my application so that I don't have to provide my stencil file when distributing application. I don't know how to access that file in code. My function needs file path to load that .vss file, so really what I don't know is, when that file is compiled along with application, how can I get it's path, because I need to provide a string as function parameter.

Comment: I've never worked with the Visio control, do you need to provide an actual file system path?  Or can you pass it a stream or array of bytes, etc?

Comment: Distribute your app in a single file named setup.exe

Comment: James - Well it says it wants a path.
Hans - That's what I was trying to avoid

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my recollection, you do need to provide a file system path to the Visio API in order to open a *.vss stencil file.

How are you embedding it in your application? Perhaps you could read it from its embedded location, and write it out to a user app data location, and then reference it *after* it's written out to disk on a per-user basis.